# ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: apartment_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I am trying to submit a "create" method on an apartment model, which returns exception:

rake routes:

`POST /api/v1/owners/:owner_id/apartments(.:format) api/v1/apartments#create {:format=>"json"}`

I have created an API for owners & apartments:

**owner.rb**

```
class Owner < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :apartments

  #Validations
  validates_presence_of :name, :email, :password_digest
  validates :email, uniqueness: true

  #encrypt password
  has_secure_password

end
```

**apartment.rb**

```
class Apartment < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :owner

end
```

getting an error while submitting request with postman with all permitted params.

```
{
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "#<ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or 
the value is empty: apartment>"
...
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is from part of your `controller` & `view` & not model. From view, params are passed where it does not include `apartment` key.

And you are looking for `params[:apartment]` in controller code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

I do not have a view, I send a post request using POSTMAN.

I send it to this URL:
`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/owners/1/apartments`

Comment: can you be more specific? How can I pass apartment exactly if it is only now being created using the api request.

Answer (score 0):

Had to remove the require, since I don't use a "new" form. And also add an owner_Id permit. Works as expected now.